# Integration through partial fractions with complex roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In integrating the following: $\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}$ I am trying to use partial fraction decomposition as follows:

$\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2} = \frac{Ax + B}{x^2+2x+3} + \frac{Cx + D}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}$

Which gives me:

$1 = (Ax + B)(x^2 +2x +3) + (Bx + C)$

And that gets me back to where I started.

$\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use partial fractions? Notice that $\left(x^2 + 2x + 3\right)^2\equiv\left((x + 1)^2 + 2\right)^2$. And then apply an appropriate [reduction formula](https://www.math24.net/reduction-formulas-integrals/).

Comment: Please write this as an answer, @an4s.  I will upvote it.  I think it provides just the right amount of a nudge lacking in the current answer.

Comment: @amWhy done....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is already written as partial fractions.

It seems you want:

$\begin{align*}
  \int \frac{d x}{(x^2 + 2 x + 3)^2}
    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{d u}{(u^2 + 1)^2} \qquad u = \sqrt{2} (x + 1)
\end{align*}$

This last one yields to a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: I think you skip a step or two too many for this to be helpful for an asker at this level.  It does not even provide a sufficient hint to be helpful to this user.

Comment: Thank you very much vonbrand. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Notice that $\left(x^2 + 2x + 3\right)^2\equiv\left((x + 1)^2 + 2\right)^2$. That is,

$$\int\frac1{\left(x^2 + 2x + 3\right)^2}\,\mathrm dx\equiv\int\frac1{\left((x + 1)^2 + 2\right)^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Let $u = x + 1\implies\mathrm du = \mathrm dx$. So,

$$\int\frac1{\left((x + 1)^2 + 2\right)^2}\,\mathrm dx\equiv\int\frac1{\left(u^2 + 2\right)^2}\,\mathrm du.$$

Now, apply an appropriate [reduction formula](https://www.math24.net/reduction-formulas-integrals/).

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for posting!

Comment: Thank you very much, an4s! :)

Comment: it''s plus 2  at the denominator  $\left(x^2 + 2x + 3\right)^2\equiv\left((x + 1)^2 + \color{red}{2}\right)^2$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need he partial fractions decomposition: as already observed, the substitution $u=x+1$ results in having to compute the integral $\;\int\frac{\mathrm du}{(u^2+2)^2}$.

Now this integral pertains to a well-known type:
$$I_n=\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{(x^2+a^2)^n},$$
which is easily computed though a recursion formula. Indeed

- $I_1=\dfrac1a\,\arctan \dfrac xa$.
- To establish the recursion formula, use integration by parts for $I_n$:

Setting $u=\dfrac1{(x^2+a^2)^n},\;\mathrm dv=\mathrm dx$, whence $\;\mathrm du=\dfrac{-2n x}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dx,\;v= x$, so
$$I_n=\frac x{(x^2+a^2)^n}+2n\int\frac {x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}=\frac x{(x^2+a^2)^n}+2n(I_n-a^2I_{n+1}),$$
whence the relation
$$I_{n+1}=\frac1{2na^2}\frac x{(x^2+a^2)^n}+\frac{2n-1}{2na^2}I_n.$$